# Rotate an image before upload it on the server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, upload

i have a little problem with upload images.
Sometimes, someone, upload photos in a wrong orientation.
Whant i want to do is rotate images before send it to my server.
Is this possible?

I know that i can use the function `imagerotate()` from **php** but i can use it after the image has been uploaded.

Is there any way via javascript (or Jquery) to rotate the image and then pass the information to the server through php?

Now i made something like this:

I use [jQueryRotate.js](http://jqueryrotate.com/)

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="file" name="file">
<div id="preview"></div>
<br>
<a href="#" id="counter" class="row"><- counter</a>
    <select id="degree">
        <option>90</option>
    </select>
<a href="#" id="clockwise" class="row">clockwise -></a>
<hr>
<button type="submit">save image</button>
</form>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.row').click(function(){
    var a = $('img').getRotateAngle();
    var d = Math.abs($('#degree').val());
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'counter'){
       //d = -Math.abs(+a - +d);
        d = a - d;
    }
    else{d = +a + +d;}

    $('img').rotate({animateTo:d});
});

/* image preview */
$('#file').change(function(){
    var oFReader = new FileReader();
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    console.log(this.files[0]);
    oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
        $('#preview').html('<img src="'+oFREvent.target.result+'">');
    };
});
});
```

But i can't transfer the 'rotation' to upload file, i think....

Thank you very much!

Comment: JavaScript rotation change the view not the real image.

Comment: You need to draw the image on canvas, rotate the canvas and then read the data from canvas to get the rotated image

Comment: Can you show me a quick example? Thanks!

No other method besides canvas? Because older browsers do not support html 5

Comment: This should do what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38734035/php-rotate-image-from-request-file/40330390#40330390

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the approach I took:

Allow the user to rotate the image in the browser.  As they do this, set the value of a hidden input field to the angle of rotation.

Then when the image gets posted to PHP, you can read the rotation field and process the image.

Comment: Actually, at a distance of years is what I did

Answer (score -1):

To rotate the image in Javascript you can use this simple function.  Just use a single rotate button (as opposed to both rotate right and rotate left), and this function will just cycle through the four options.

```
function rotatePreview() {
  var img = document.getElementById('preview-photo');
  var currentrotate = img.style.transform;
  var newrotate = '';
  var rotatevalue = 0;

  switch(currentrotate){
    case '':
      newrotate = 'rotate(90deg)';
      rotatevalue = 90;
      break;
    case 'rotate(90deg)':
      newrotate = 'rotate(180deg)';
      rotatevalue = 180;
      break;
    case 'rotate(180deg)':
      newrotate = 'rotate(270deg)';
      rotatevalue = 270;
      break;
    case 'rotate(270deg)':
      newrotate = '';
      rotatevalue = 0;
      break;
  }

  img.style.transform = newrotate;
  document.getElementById("rotatevalue").value = rotatevalue;
}
```

This function rotates the image an additional 90 degrees further than the current rotate, and also saves the new rotate value in a hidden input which you can then submit to your PHP and rotate the image by the same amount in your PHP before saving it on the server.