# PHP Rotate Image from request file

Tags: php, image, laravel, upload, request

I am now using the following method to store an image to server from input file type

```
$image = $request->file('file');
$filename = $item->itemId . '.png';
Storage::disk('s3')->put('/'.$filename, file_get_contents($image), 'public');
```

and I found method to rotate the image with PHP

```
$filename = 'test.jpg';
$degrees = 180;
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
$rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);
imagejpeg($rotate);
```

but I dont know how implement the code with $request->file('file')

Thanks!

Comment: Try to use http://image.intervention.io/ ! You can make an image directly from `$request->file('file')` !

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you are getting your functions from, imagecreatefromjpeg() and imagerotate(), but if you just use PHP's own, available functions (provided by Imagick), you can do something much simpler...

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image_filehandle = fopen('some/file.jpg', 'a+');
$image->readImageFile($image_filehandle );

$image->rotateImage("FFFFFF", 90);  # Rotate 90 degrees, keep background of "FFFFFF" (white)

$image_icon_filehandle = fopen('some/file-rotated.jpg', 'a+');
$image->writeImageFile($image_icon_filehandle);
```

The background color ("FFFFFF") is applied here if the image rotates and leaves a certain amount of background (does not happen for rotate degrees in increments of 90).